# Getting child targets for mouse click event in OpenFL

Tags: types, mouseevent, haxe, rtti, openfl

I have a stage with multiple child object of different types. I have an event listener on the stage. I'd like to get the target child object on a mouse click so I can handle clicks on different object types.

Something along the lines of:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onClick(e:Event):Void
{
    var target = e.target
    // if target type is Foo
    //     target.aFooMethod();
    // else if target type is Bar
    //     target.aBarMethod();

}
```

Whats the correct way of doing this? Tracing `e.target` seems to print the correct object type but I am unable to call any of the objects methods.

I vaguely remember in actionscript 3 being able to use `target.name` but return null in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your question is mostly about runtime type identification (RTTI) and type casting. Haxe provides a number of utilities in the [`Type`](http://api.haxe.org/Type.html) and [`Reflect`](http://api.haxe.org/Reflect.html) classes for dealing with this.

For your code, it looks like you want specifically:

```
if (Std.is(target, Foo)) (cast target:Foo).aFooMethod();
else if (Std.is(target, Bar)) (cast target:Bar).aBarMethod();
```

Or perhaps:

```
if (Std.is(target, Foo)) {
  var targetAsFoo:Foo = cast target;
  targetAsFoo.aFooMethod();
} else if (Std.is(target, Bar)) {
  var targetAsBar:Bar = cast target;
  targetAsBar.aBarMethod();
}
```

Here is an example demonstrating a number of utilities which could help you, including `Std.is`, interfaces, `Type.getClass`, type casting, etc: http://try.haxe.org/#3C192

The code is as follows:

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
 
        function identify(tgt:Dynamic)
        {
            trace("1: "+tgt);
            trace("2: "+Type.typeof(tgt));
            trace("3: "+Type.getClassName(tgt));
            trace("4: "+Type.getClass(Type.getClassName(tgt)));
            trace("5: "+Std.is(tgt, Something));
 
            if (Std.is(tgt, Something)) {
            // Can cast explicitly
                var casted:Something = cast tgt;
                trace("Got a Something named: "+casted.name);
            }
 
            if (Std.is(tgt, Something)) {
            // Can cast implicitly
                var casted:Something = untyped tgt;
                trace("Got a Something named: "+casted.name);
            }
 
            if (Std.is(tgt, Something)) {
            // Can cast in an inline style, (obj:Type)
                trace("Got a Something named: "+(tgt:Something).name);
            }
 
            if (Std.is(tgt, IHasAName)) {
            // Can cast to an interface, if you prefer
                var i_casted:IHasAName = (tgt:IHasAName);
                trace("Got a IHasAName named: "+i_casted.name);
            }
 
            // Can reflect to see if the name field exists:
            if (Reflect.hasField(tgt, "name")) {
                trace("tgt has a name: "+Reflect.field(tgt, "name"));
            }
            if (Reflect.hasField(tgt, "length")) {
                trace("tgt has a length: "+Reflect.field(tgt, "length"));
            }
        }
        
        trace("----------------------------------");
        trace("Calling identify with a Something:");
        trace("----------------------------------");
        var a = new Something("foo", 3);
        identify(a);
 
        trace("----------------------------------");
        trace("Calling identify with a String:");
        trace("----------------------------------");
        var b = "a string";
        identify(b);
 
        trace("----------------------------------");
        trace("Calling identify with anonymous:");
        trace("----------------------------------");
        var c =  { "name" : "anonymous" };
        identify(c);
 
    }
}
 
class Something implements IHasAName
{
    public var name:String;
    public var length:Int;
    public function new(name:String, length:Int)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.length = length;
    }
}
 
interface IHasAName {
    public var name:String;
}
```

The output is:

```
14:41:24:664   ----------------------------------
14:41:24:664   Calling identify with a Something:
14:41:24:664   ----------------------------------
14:41:24:664   1: { name : foo, length : 3 }
14:41:24:665   2: TClass({ __name__ : [Something] })
14:41:24:665   3: null
14:41:24:665   4: null
14:41:24:665   5: true
14:41:24:665   Got a Something named: foo
14:41:24:665   Got a Something named: foo
14:41:24:665   Got a Something named: foo
14:41:24:665   Got a IHasAName named: foo
14:41:24:665   tgt has a name: foo
14:41:24:665   tgt has a length: 3
14:41:24:666   ----------------------------------
14:41:24:666   Calling identify with a String:
14:41:24:666   ----------------------------------
14:41:24:666   1: a string
14:41:24:666   2: TClass({ __name__ : [String] })
14:41:24:666   3: null
14:41:24:666   4: null
14:41:24:666   5: false
14:41:24:666   tgt has a length: 8
14:41:24:667   ----------------------------------
14:41:24:667   Calling identify with anonymous:
14:41:24:667   ----------------------------------
14:41:24:667   1: { name : anonymous }
14:41:24:667   2: TObject
14:41:24:667   3: null
14:41:24:668   4: null
14:41:24:668   5: false
14:41:24:668   tgt has a name: anonymous
```

> I vaguely remember in actionscript 3 being able to use target.name but return null in this case.

In AS3, `event.target` is of type `DisplayObject`, and all [DisplayObjects have a `.name` property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#name), which is why you could do that in AS3.

OpenFL's [`Event.target`](http://api.openfl.org/openfl/events/Event.html#target) is an [`IEventDispatcher`](http://api.openfl.org/openfl/events/IEventDispatcher.html), which isn't specifically associated with display classes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your stage has a "name" value? 
From my tests, using `event.target.name` should work.

To confirm, try to use `event.target.id` since the framework sets a default value even if its not manually specified.

Goodluck.